# Building grouped barplot within stacked barplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

```r
Treatment<- c(rep("Burkholderia", 2), rep("Cut", 2), rep("Male", 2,), rep("Split", 2),rep("Burkholderia", 2), rep("Cut", 2), rep("Male", 2),rep("Split",2))
Infection<- rep(c("Pos","Neg"), 8) 
Lifestage<- c(rep("Young",4), rep("Old", 4)) 
Value<- c(0,7,3,27,2,25,0,23,16,0,12,2,11,2,28,0)
groupbar<- data.frame(Treatment, Lifestage, Infection, Value)
head(Prop_at_lifestage)
ggplot(data = groupbar, aes(y = Value, x = Lifestage, fill = Infection)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position='fill') +  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid( ~ Treatment)
```

I input the above code trying to produce a figure which showed the proportion of each infection state (positive or negative) at each life stage (young or old), separated by Treatment. I can seem to figure out why it is only outputting the way it is.

[image]

Comment: `Prop_at_lifestage` is missing. Also check your generating  functions should Lifestage be defined as: `Lifestage<- c(rep("Young",8), rep("Old", 8)) `

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! What exactly is the issue you're having with the plot? Is it that you don't have bars for old or young in some of the facets? Looking at your data that makes sense as each of the Treatment groups only has old or young. We would be able to help more with a more detailed description you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help with a reproducible example!